# How search for items in list1 in a second list2 and return a data-frame with items that are equal

Tags: python, string, pandas, hash, string-search

Python, How search for items in list1 in a second list2 and return a data-frame with items that are equal.

Anyone would help, I need to find what values are the some in both strings, then return the id related to the row.

Following how I failed trying to return in another dataframe the values that is equal.

## This is reference list1 (binglist)

```
binglist

['31664745', '283494006', '283494005', '283494009', '283494007', 
'283494008','283703957', '283703955', '283703956', '283703954',
 '283703960', '31454872', '283536236', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
 '0', '0', '0']
```

## This is list that we need to search on, list2 (Data-frame)

cw["campaignname"].unique()

```
cw["campaignname"]

array(['35119190', '31664745', '4899110', '804530544', '325772660',
       '283494005', '64002140', '272351300', '2016404066', '753857250',
       '6.12855E+12', '283703956', '283703960',
       '169278078', 'business', '636589579', '52106838', 'science',
       '820812876', 'art'], dtype=object)
```

## Following how I failed trying to return in another dataframe the values that is equal.

```
# using a set makes the later `x in keep` test faster
keep= set(binglist)


# -> Loop all cw["campaignname"] records only(Bing records)  
# -> If there is a equal value 
# -> return the id 

b = [x= cw["id"] for x in cw["campaignname"].filter(["Bing", "BingBrand", "BingNonBrand"])  if x in bing]

# it give me empty result
```

it give me empty result

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: The strings that are equally. Like 35119190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually using `isin` with `loc`

```
Yourdf=cw[cw['campaignname'].isin(keep)].copy()
Yourdf['id']
```

Comment: Thanks WeNYoBen, I will try it out tomorrow first thing in the morning and I let you know

Comment: It works, only issue is.. it delete the ones that are different and just keep the ones that are the some.

In this case, I do need to find the wrong ones and then FIX them.

Comment: @PeterBrito worngone=cw[~cw['campaignname'].isin(keep)].copy()